# How to construct shell redirection on command line

Tags: shell, pipe, redirection

Consider the following command in Unix:

```
echo 0123456789 | cat >/tmp/foo &> /tmp/bar
```

The echo is sent to /tmp/bar.

However, what I really want is to redirect the stdout and stderr output of the cat command and not take its input.

What is the proper syntax to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out:

```
echo 0123456789 | (cat >/tmp/foo) &> /tmp/bar
```